# Java - Setting a distinct bit of an integer to zero

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

Here is the description:

> In order to stop the Mad Coder evil genius you need to decipher the encrypted message he sent to his minions. The message contains several numbers that, when typed into a supercomputer, will launch a missile into the sky blocking out the sun, and making all the people on Earth grumpy and sad.
>
> You figured out that some numbers have a modified single digit in their binary representation. More specifically, in the given number n the kth bit from the right was initially set to 0, but its current value might be different. It's now up to you to write a function that will change the kth bit of n back to 0.
>
> Example
>
> For n = 37 and k = 3, the output should be
>   killKthBit(n, k) = 33.
>
> 3710 = 1001012 ~> 1000012 = 3310.
>
> For n = 37 and k = 4, the output should be
>
> killKthBit(n, k) = 37.
>
> The 4th bit is 0 already (looks like the Mad Coder forgot to encrypt this number), so the answer is still 37."

Here is a solution I found and I cannot understand it:

```
int killKthBit(int n, int k)
{
  return n & ~(1 << (k - 1)) ;
}
```

Can someone explain what the solution does and its syntax?

Answer (score 5):

**Detailed explanation of your function**

The expression `1 << (k - 1)` shifts the number `1` exactly `k-1` times to the left so as an example for an 8 Bit number and `k = 4`:

Before shift: `00000001`
After Shift: `00010000`

This marks the bit to *kill*. You see, `1` was shifted to the *fourth* position, as it was on position *zero*. The operator `~` negates each bit, meaning `1` becomes `0` and `0` becomes `1`. For our example:

Before negation: `00010000`
After negation: `11101111`

At last, `&` executes a **bit-wise AND** on two operands. Let us say, we have a number `n = 17`, which is `00010001` in binary. Our example now is:

`00010001 & 11101111 = 00000001`

This is, because each bit of both numbers is compared by **AND** on **the same position**. Only positions, where both numbers have a `1` remain `1`, all others are set to `0`. Consequently, only position zero remains `1`.

Overall your method `int killKthBit(int n, int k)` does exactly that with binary operators, it sets the bit on position `k` of number `n` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try

```
//Returns a number that has all bits same as n
// except the k'th bit which is made 0
int turnOffK(int n, int k)
{
    // k must be greater than 0
    if (k <= 0) return n;

    // Do & of n with a number with all set bits except
    // the k'th bit
    return (n & ~(1 << (k - 1)));
}
```